# Finding the column name in php for a mysql query when a particular field has matched

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query such that I am searching for a field in 10 columns such as

```
price_squery1 = "select * from table 
where table_category1 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category2 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category3 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category4 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category5 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category6 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category7 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category8 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category9 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category10 = '$category[0]'";
$price_sresult1 = mysql_query($price_squery1);
```

I want to know which column the field has matched without using for loop for searching each column. Is there a way to find directly which column the match has occured. I am new to sql, please help.

Comment: Some formatting wouldn't hurt.

Comment: Yes, there is, it's called [database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). Learn that first, normalize your relations, and then come back and ask again if you did not manage to do whatever you were up to in the first place.

Comment: i know about that.. problem is i have to work without normalizing so that i dont have to create more tables. I needed a way without normalizing

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how to do this in SQL, but you could just compare the value you search, and the value each column returns with PHP?

There might be more than one column matching the value..

```
$result = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query($price_squery1);
if ($result['table_category1'] == $category[0])
    // found in category1
if ($result['table_category2'] == $category[0])
    // found in category2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
price_squery1 = "select 
if(table_category1 = '$category[0]', \'table_category1\',if(table_category2 = '$category[0]',\'table_category2\',if(table_category3 = '$category[0]',\'table_category3\',if(table_category4 = '$category[0]',\'table_category4\', None)))) matched_category
t.* from table t
where table_category1 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category2 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category3 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category4 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category5 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category6 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category7 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category8 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category9 = '$category[0]' or 
table_category10 = '$category[0]'";
$price_sresult1 = mysql_query($price_squery1);
```

I modify the query for the first a few categories you can extend it adding more if statements.